# Spring mvc validate a primitive with @RequestBody doesn't work

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I'm trying to validate an email that I receive from the post request body but it's doesn't work !

```
@RequestMapping(value = "myservice/emails", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String requestFoo(@RequestBody @Email String email) {
    return email;
}
```

When I send a request with a string that doesn't respect the email regex the function is executed and I receive a 200 status code.

Even do I add the @Valid annotation the result is always the same.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "myservice/emails", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String testValidation(@Valid @RequestBody @Email String email) {
    return email;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Start with Spring 3.2 `@RequestBody` method argument may be followed by Errors object, hence allowing handling of validation errors in the same `@RequestMapping` :

```
@RequestMapping(value = "myservice/emails", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ResponseEntity<String> testValidation(@Valid @RequestBody @Email String email, Errors errors) {
  if (errors.hasErrors()) {
  return ResponseEntity.badRequest().body(ValidationErrorBuilder.fromBindingErrors(errors));
        }
    return email;
}
```

And create a custom validator  :

```
public class ValidationErrorBuilder {

    public static ValidationError fromBindingErrors(Errors errors) {
        ValidationError error = new ValidationError("Validation failed. " + errors.getErrorCount() + " error(s)");
        for (ObjectError objectError : errors.getAllErrors()) {
            error.addValidationError(objectError.getDefaultMessage());
        }
        return error;
    }
}
```